# Azure Active Directory - Assign to group

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, directoryservices

Is it possible to assign an application (as an Application or Service Principal) to a group programatically, via the graph client or API? (Including the app user credentials needed to allow access of the members of the group to the app)

I searched everywhere and couldn't find documentation for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, 'Applications' in Azure AD are used to segment authorization and settings within Azure AD. It creates a trust between Azure AD and your application. The Application is not a User.

Users are Azure AD entities that have identity and can be authorized to access resources (like an Application). Users can be added to groups. See the below link for the Azure AD graph API documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/groups-operations#AddGroupMembers

And the documentation on what a user entity looks like:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#UserEntity

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer emseetea, but we do have a little more than that.

Back to the original question - can you programmatically "assign a group to an application".  The answer is yes, using appRoleAssignments on the service principal.  The service principal represents an application instance, that typically gets provisioned as part of a consent grant. On this tenant specific app instance (service principal) you can attach tenant specific permissions and policy.  Permissions get created as part of consent, but you can also programmatically assign an application role (defined by the application) to a user or group.  If no application role is assigned, then you can make a "default" assignment.  You can find a little more on this topic here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2014/12/12/announcing-the-new-version-of-graph-api-api-version-1-5.aspx which describes a little about this with some sample REST API calls.

This same operation is also possible through the client library.  You can take a look at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console. Look at the section titled "#region Assign Direct Permission".  This shows how to assign an app role to a user.  You can do the same thing on a group too.  If your app doesn't specify any app roles, set the appRoleAssignment.Id to a zero GUID.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Yes, application roles are very useful but, respectfully, that isn't an answer to the question that the OP asked. It's hard to divine the motivation behind the OP's original question without more details but you might be right in thinking application roles are applicable to the OP's underlying goals. I know I learned something from your answer so thanks for that. :)

Comment: Basically what I want to do is mimic adding a gallery app to the Azure Active Directory. that I was successful in doing by adding a service principal with the Id of the app from the Azure Gallery. When I manually (through the Azure Portal) assign the app to a group, it asks for credentials of an admin from the app (say, Office 365, dynamics CRM, etc.). Where do I put these credentials in code when adding an app role?